# Control vue navigation from Testcafe

Tags: testing, vue.js, vuejs2, e2e-testing, testcafe

For testing Vue2 I use [testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/).
Command to run tests

```
testcafe firefox test/e2e/specs/ --app \"npm run dev\"
--app-init-delay 20000 -S -s test/e2e/screenshots
```

**Test file**

```
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from 'testcafe';
const devServer = require('../../../webpack/devServer');

fixture(`Getting Started`)
// Load the URL your development server runs on.
    .page(`http://localhost:${devServer.port}/#/login`);

test('test login', async t => {
    const userSelector = await new Selector('.login-squere input[type="text"]');
    const passSelector = await new Selector('.login-squere input[type="password"]');
    const logiIn = await new Selector('.login-squere button');
    await t.typeText(userSelector, 'manager')
        .typeText(passSelector, 'manager')
        .click(logiIn);
});
```

I expect after .click(logiIn) site to route to **/#/projects**, but nothing happens
I added to test

```
await t.typeText(userSelector, 'manager')
        .typeText(passSelector, 'manager')
        .click(logiIn)
        .navigateTo(`http://localhost:${devServer.port}/#/projects`);
```

And again no result. If I set **.page** to **/#/projects** it wil be rerouted to login.

So I can test only login page, because I cant make testcafe route Vue to next view.

---

This problem appears only if after login click we have ajax. TestCafe doesnt have request handler, so it is better to try something else for e2e

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem on https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/examples but I could not.

As I understand, the problem is connected with the router.

Can you share an example to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
test('login', async t => {
  await login(t);
});
```

and separate your code into a new function:

```
const login = async t => {
  const userSelector = await new Selector('.login-squere input[type="text"]');
    const passSelector = await new Selector('.login-squere input[type="password"]');
    const logiIn = await new Selector('.login-squere button');
    await t.typeText(userSelector, 'manager')
        .typeText(passSelector, 'manager')
        .click(logiIn);
};
```